# Python IMAP search, search results exhaust all memory

Tags: python, search, imaplib

I'm trying to fetch all auto-reponse emails from a specific address in Python using imaplib. Everything worked fine for weeks but now each time I run my program all my RAM is consumed (several GB!) and the script end up being killed by the OOM killer.

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('server')
M.LOGIN('user', 'pass')
M.SELECT()
date = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1)).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
result, data = M.uid('search', None, '(SENTON %s HEADER FROM "auto@site.com" NOT SUBJECT "RE:")' % date)
...
```

I'm sure that less than 100 emails of a few kilobytes should be returned. What could be the matter here ? Or is there a way to limit the number of emails returned ?
Thx!

Comment: (1) I assume the capitalisation in your code is a typo, since it wouldn't work as-is.  (2) You won't get any email back, just UIDs (so it doesn't matter what size the messages are).  (3) Try adding "M.debug = 4" before the search - this will show you what's sent to and received from the server.

Comment: WRT to limiting, you can search only within a subset of the messages, which has the same effect (except that you're limiting the *maximum* results, not the *total* results).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added 'M.debug=4' before M.select() and now everything is happening as before. The code is identical as well as the IMAP search string. If the problem happens again I will paste the debut output here.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to know for sure what the cause is, without being able to reproduce the problem (and certainly not without seeing the complete program which triggers the problem, and knowing the version of all dependencies you're using).

However, here's my best *guess*.  Several versions of Python include a very memory-wasteful implementation of imaplib.  The problem is particularly evident on Windows, but not limited to that platform.

The core of the problem is the way strings are allocated when read from a socket, and the way imaplib reads strings from sockets.

When reading from a socket, Python first allocates a buffer large enough to handle as many bytes as the application asks for.  This may be something reasonable sounding, perhaps 16 kB.  Then data is read into that buffer and the buffer is resized *down* to fit the number of bytes actually read.

The efficiency of this operation depends on the quality of the platform re-allocation implementation.  Resizing a buffer may end up moving it to a more suitable location, where the smaller size avoids wasting much memory.  Or it may just mark the tail part of the memory, no longer allocated as part of that region, as re-usable (and it may even be able to re-use it in practice).  Or it might end up wasting that technically unallocated memory.

Imagine the cumulative effects of that memory being wasted if you have to read a few dozen kB of data, and the data arrives from the network a few dozen bytes at a time.  Worse, imagine if the data is really trickling, and you only get a few bytes at a time.  Or if you're reading a very "large" response of several hundred kB.

The amount of memory wasted - effectively allocated by the process, but not usable in any meaningful way - can be huge.  100 kB of data, read 5 bytes at a time requires 20480 buffers.  If each buffer starts off as 16 kB and is *unsuccessfully* shrunk, causing them to **remain** at 16Kb, then you've allocated at least 320MB of memory to hold that 100 kB of data.

Some versions of imaplib exacerbated this problem by introducing multiple layers of buffering and copying.  A very old version (hopefully not one you're actually using) even read 1 byte at a time (which would result in 1.6GB of memory usage in the above scenario).

Of course, this problem *usually* doesn't show up on Linux, where the re-allocator is not so bad.  And at various points in previous Python releases (previous to the most recent 2.x release), the bug was "fixed", so I wouldn't expect to see it show up these days.  And this doesn't explain why your program ran fine for a while before failing this way.

But it is my best guess.